# Cancel connection is boost::asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, connect, disconnect

From the standard [SSL client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp) example. Say I call this function.

```
    boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator,
                               boost::bind(&SSLClient::handle_connect, this,
                                           boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

But then the function is called, and the program is connecting. I would like to cancel my request and stop the connection! How can I do that?

Special case: Say I have those objects in a thread. Is there a way to do it in this case?

Now if I try to do this, the program simply doesn't respond. I don't see a way to force it to stop!

Comment: "Now if I try to do this" - do what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want ¹.

1. You could hard-stop the service (`service.stop()`). But this leaves you no control over all running operations. It's the "nuclear" approach, so to say.
2. The controlled way would be to call [`cancel()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel.html)

   > *Cancel all asynchronous operations associated with the socket.*

   ```
   socket_.cancel()
   ```

Now, you have the additional task of maintaining the lifetime of your connection object (presumably the `this` in your bound completion handler). A very common pattern to use is to make the connection class derive from `enable_shared_from_this` and bind the completion handler to `shared_from_this()` instead of just `this`.

That way, the shared connection object will automatically "go away" after the last pending async operation has been canceled, and you don't have to worry about leaking connection objects.

¹ short of `exit`, `abort`, `quick_exit` etc. :)